# Discord.js Error: client.channels.cache.get retorna null

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Estoy haciendo un bot de discord, que cuando escriba en la consola, salga mi mensaje mediante el bot; la consola me dice *canal no existe*.

Adjunto código.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const readline = require('readline');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILD_MESSAGES', 'DIRECT_MESSAGES'] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot está listo como: ${client.user.tag}!`);

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.on('line', (input) => {
        let channel = client.channels.cache.get('1222599758607028255');
        if (!channel) {
            console.log('El canal no existe');
            return;
        }
        channel.send(input);
    });
});

// Asegúrate de reemplazar 'tu-token' con el token de tu bot.
client.login('TOKEN-BOT');
```

Comment: ¿Porque no sacas esta linea let channel = client.channels.cache.get('1222599758607028255'); del evento line de r1 y lo dejas en el evento ready del client?. ha, llevate el console.log tambien para ver si te sigue retornando null.